# How to recreate Geometry by changing colour when user select at any point of node

Tags: swift, uikit, scenekit, 3d-model

I have a 3D SCN model i am showing it in SCNode in SceneKit, I want to implement a code when user touch on any part of node i want to change the colour of that point user select and recreate the geometry by changing colour.

I Don't get any thing related it please help me to find it out

Comment: Hi Moinuddin! I'm not sure I understand what you want. 
But if you want to know where in a node the user touched you have this information directly in the touch event.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.